# Injecting Custom Pipe for Unit Test

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-test

I have extended the `DecimalPipe` and used the way and for the unit test it is failing. I've registered the pipe with the `TestBed` as well.

> ```
> `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyDecimalPipe -> MyDecimalPipe]: 
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for MyDecimalPipe!
> ```

**MyDecimalPipe.ts**

```
import { DecimalPipe, registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myDecimal'
})
export class MyDecimalPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value: any, args?: any) : any {

        registerLocaleData(localeFr);

        return super.transform(value, args, 'fr');
    }
}
```

**MyDecimalPipe.spec.ts**

```
import { MyDecimalPipe } from './my-decimal.pipe';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import localFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { registerLocaleData, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common'

describe('MyDecimalPipe', () => {
    let pipe: MyDecimalPipe;
    let value: number;
    let defaultLocale: string = 'en-US';

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations:[MyDecimalPipe],
        providers:[MyDecimalPipe]
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        value = 0;

        registerLocaleData(localFr);
        pipe = new MyDecimalPipe(defaultLocale);
    });

    it('create an instance', () => {
        //arrange

        //act

        //assert
        expect(pipe).toBeTruthy(); 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations:[MyDecimalPipe],
  providers:[MyDecimalPipe]
});
```

I may be wrong, but I think you don't need it since you are testing the MyDecimalPipe.